# Update of a column failing when I use a CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update, case

Am trying to update few columns based on different conditions using CASE statement. But I don't see column being getting updated. When do a SELECT, the CASE works perfectly fine. Below is the sample update statement with single column which is failing.

```
UPDATE D
SET EnglandOrWales = CASE WHEN Name = 'crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales'
                         THEN C.Data ELSE D.EnglandOrWales END
FROM @CorDeaths D
INNER JOIN CustomFieldData C
    ON C.EntityId = D.EntityID
INNER JOIN MetaData.MetaDataCustomField M
    ON C.MetaDataCustomFieldUId = M.MetaDataCustomFieldUId 
WHERE
    MetaDataAttributeHierarchyGroupId IN (50, 53)
```

Below SELECT works fine and returns NA wherever there is no match and returns a C.Data for matching records.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Name = 'crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales'
         THEN C.Data ELSE 'NA' END 
FROM @CorDeaths D
INNER JOIN CustomFieldData C
    ON C.EntityId = D.EntityID
INNER JOIN MetaData.MetaDataCustomField M
    ON C.MetaDataCustomFieldUId = M.MetaDataCustomFieldUId 
WHERE
    MetaDataAttributeHierarchyGroupId IN (50, 53)
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: No error, the column remains NULL

Comment: Well, `D.EnglandOrWales` is not `'NA'` and might itself be `null`. Isn't it?

Comment: If none of the names match `crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales` in the update, then your code just writes `EnglandOrWales` back on itself.  And if all those values began as `NULL` they will remain as `NULL`.  I think your data/logic is the problem.

Comment: There are 4 matching records and 20 not matching records. may be the last record which is not a match updating all the previous records back to NULL?

Comment: As Arkadiusz posted as a comment to the answer below if the only issues is that your nulls are not being changed then you need to deal with nulls using isnull or coalesce or adding (Or Name IS NULL).

You can't compare nulls.  Check out this article https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp  "It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>"

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate updates and add where istead of CASE:

```
UPDATE D SET EnglandOrWales=C.Data
FROM @CorDeaths D INNER JOIN CustomFieldData C ON C.EntityId=D.EntityID INNER JOIN MetaData.MetaDataCustomField M
    ON C.MetaDataCustomFieldUId = M.MetaDataCustomFieldUId 
WHERE MetaDataAttributeHierarchyGroupId in (50,53) and Name  = 'crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales'

UPDATE D SET EnglandOrWales=D.EnglandOrWales
FROM @CorDeaths D INNER JOIN CustomFieldData C ON C.EntityId=D.EntityID INNER JOIN MetaData.MetaDataCustomField M
    ON C.MetaDataCustomFieldUId = M.MetaDataCustomFieldUId 
WHERE MetaDataAttributeHierarchyGroupId in (50,53) and ISNULL(Name,'')  <> 'crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales'
```

Comment: This should not be necessary.

Comment: there are more than 10 columns to update with just one condition being different. Hence doing the same table joins for more than 10 times may not be optimal way.

Comment: Ok, but you can check if this works for testing only. Maybe you will be closer to resolve the issue doing this step by step. Please give info if it works or not.

Comment: @Arkadiusz: If I put a separate UPDATEs then it works.

Comment: Maybe put this: CASE WHEN INSULL(Name,'') = 'crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales' instead of this: CASE WHEN Name = 'crnDeathOccurredInEnglandOrWales'